# Can't link qwt in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, qwt

I use LIBS flag to link qwt library to my project. So in .pro of my project i have

```
LIBS += -L/home/Desktop/qwt-6.0.1/lib -lqwt
```

But anyway Qt does not recognize qwt classes. What i'm missing ??

Comment: Is this an error with compiling or linking? It would help if you edited your question to include your error message.

Comment: no , when i try to type a class it just saying that cannot find such class

Comment: Does your IDE simply indicate no such class is found, or do you get a compile/link error? Please show us the exact error your getting.

Comment: it's simply indicate no such class is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to include the headers.

Try to add the following

```
INCLUDE += /home/Desktop/qwt-6.0.1/include
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. you have to use -L switch and set your library path as bellow:

LIBS+= -L "/home/Desktop/qwt-6.0.1/lib/" -lqwt

adding above line to the .pro file resolve compiling error of the project. then for running Application you should link libqwt.so.6.1.3 to default library path on your system using bellow command:

```
ln -s /home/Desktop/qwt-6.0.1/lib/libqwt.so.6.1.3 /usr/lib/libqwt.so.6
```

or simply update LD_LIBRARY_PATH using below command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/Desktop/qwt-6.0.1/lib/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I advice you to use the first approach.